# Clip-Path with inline SVG in Firefox being URL Dependent

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg

So I have a clip-path set, and, because Firefox, I have an inline-SVG set to mimic the clip-path like so

```
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clipPolygon" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <polygon points=".25 0,1 0,.75 1,0 1"></polygon>
            </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Then, in the CSS, I set `clip-path:url("/PATH_TO_FILE/index.html#clipPolygon");`, because `clip-path:url("#clipPolygon");` didn't work for some reason in Firefox.

However, when I view the webpage, `/PATH_TO_FILE/` fails to render the clip at all, but typing `/PATH_TO_FILE/index.html` as the URL renders everything perfectly.

It's worth noting that all this works just fine in Chrome. Is there something obvious I'm missing here?